# Object reference not set to an instance of an object con transaction IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted

Tags: c#, sql, .net

llevo varios dias con un problema y no encuentro la solucion.

tengo una transacion con esta propiedad `IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted`

```
  using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted }))
        {
            try
            {
               
                var CreatedsPdf = db.SoportePdfCreateds.Where(c => !c.IsCreated).Take(10).ToList();
                Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
                sw.Start();
                if (CreatedsPdf.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var item in CreatedsPdf)
                    {                           
                        if (item!=null)
                        {                                
                            string fecha = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy");
                            PdfCreatorBase pdfCreatorBase = new PdfCreatorBase("SE" + item.SoporteEntrega.Guia + fecha + ".PDF");
                            byte[] bytesConvertBack = Convert.FromBase64String(item.PdfBytes64);
                            pdfCreatorBase.CreateSoporteEntregaPdf(item.SoporteEntregaId, bytesConvertBack);
                            item.IsCreated = true;
                            item.FechaCreacion = DateTime.Now;
                            db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
                        }                            
                    }
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    sw.Stop();                 
                    scope.Complete();
                }
```

pero en esta linea  `PdfCreatorBase pdfCreatorBase = new PdfCreatorBase("SE" + item.SoporteEntrega.Guia + fecha + ".PDF");` a pesar de que tengo una validación de que si es null me da el siguiente error :

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

No se si estoy usando mal el tipo de IsolationLevel, pero no le encuentro sentido.

muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Luego de revisar el código y la información del error que mencionas, pude notar lo siguiente:

Sin dudas, `item` no es nulo porque tienes una validación que lo garantiza, sin embargo, `item` tiene la propiedad `SoporteEntrega` que es un objeto y no estás validando si es nulo o no.
Por otra parte, `SoporteEntrega` tiene la propiedad `Guia` que por ser de tipo `string`, también puediera ser nulo.

Dicho esto y en el contexto de tu pregunta, mi recomendación es que modifiques la condición
`if (item!=null)` por:
`if (item != null && item.SoporteEntrega != null && item.SoporteEntrega.Guia != null )`

Comment: Hola Pablo, si efectivamente era eso.